# Why is my React state not updating as expected?

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the NextButton I want to increment the value of the page state which is set to default at 0. In the header, I want to show value in the FormTitles array at index of page.

Currently, it increments for a second then instantly reverts back to the default value as can be seen in the [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfgxh.gif).

What is causing this issue?

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useState } from "react";
function Form() {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const FormTitles = [
    "1", 
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
  ]

  const handlePageIncrement = () => {
    setPage((currPage) => currPage + 1)
  }

  
  return (
    <FormWrapperOuter>
        <ProgressBar></ProgressBar>
        <FormWrapperInner>
        <Header><h1>{FormTitles[page]}</h1></Header>
        <Body></Body>
        <Footer>
            <PrevButton>Back</PrevButton>
            <NextButton onClick={handlePageIncrement}>Next</NextButton>
        </Footer>
        </FormWrapperInner>
    </FormWrapperOuter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please add code of your approach so people can help you check what is going on

Comment: My GUESS is that your "Next" button is part of a `<form>`, and after updating the value, you are allowing the form to be submitted, which causes the page to be refreshed.

Comment: @Jhilton Yes, of course. I completely forgot. I just added the code.

Comment: @TimRoberts How can I prevent the form from being submitted?

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your button

Comment: Assuming `<NextButton>` derives from the HTML `<button>`, just add `type="button"`.  The default type for a button is  "submit".

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, that worked. Thank you! I also tried e.preventDefault() and that seemed to work alright, too. Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

Comment: No, the two serve the same purpose.  Using the attribute is a tiny bit more efficient because it doesn't execute any code, but that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
let title=FormTitles[0]
const handlePageIncrement = () => {
    title=FormTitles[page+1]
    setPage((currPage) => currPage + 1)
}
```

Take a title variable that stores the value and update it when function triggers and also change this part

```
<h1>{title}</h1>
```